# Fixed sidebar inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to have a sidebar that sticks to the top when main content is being scrolled down. I've tried `position: fixed` but as I understand it doesn't work, because main body of a page is not being scrolled.
I've also tried fiddling with `overflow-y`, but didn't have any luck either.
The left side is a long image showcasing my work, and the right side is a box with description of the image.
Here is simple jsbin example: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kilelehuno/edit?html,output%22jsbin%22)

Comment: move your element outside of the `bs` modal and give higher `z-index` so it is sits on top of the modal

Answer (score 1):

So first off, I'd suggest updating your bootstrap version then using bootstrap to create said cols.
So for instance your code would read

```
<div class="bs-example">
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="containter">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-md-8 order-2 order-md-1 modal-left">long img here</div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-1 order-md-2 modal-right">this one should stick to the top while scrolling</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What this does is create a resposive version of what you have there. Once you have done this you can implement this code and edit as needed.

```
        function sticky_relocate_modal() {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div_top = $('.modal-content').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('.modal-right').addClass('modal-stick');
        } else {
            $('.modal-right').removeClass('modal-stick');
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate_modal);
            sticky_relocate_modal();
        } else {}
    });
```

What this does is check the container ('.modal-content') and check if it has been scrolled. Once scrolled you can add the class '.modal-stick' This class will have :

```
.modal-stick {
position:fixed;
right:0;
}
```

It's a long way round what you want but creates a much nices code structure and makes you able to use bootstrap to its full potencial.
See this [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) for an explanation of bootstrap.

Hope this helps. If you need any more guidance let me know and I'm more than happy to help.